# Bounded variation after a diffeomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, bounded-variation

This might be a standard property of BV functions but I have not heard about it before.

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $\phi:I\to \mathbb R$.
We say that $\phi$ is of bounded (total) variation if
$$ \sup_{ 0=x_0<\ldots < x_k < \ldots < x_n = 1 } \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |\phi(x_{k+1}) - \phi(x_k)| < \infty .$$

Questions: is it true that

- if $\phi$ is of bounded variation then for every $C^1$-diffeomorphism $p:I\to I$ the function $\phi\circ p$ is of bounded variation;
- if there exists some $C^1$-diffeomorphism $p:I\to I$ such that the function $\phi\circ p$ is of bounded variation, then $\phi$ is of bounded variation?

The same questions for $p\circ \phi$ (probably they are identical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $p\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is Lipschitz (in particular, if it is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism) with Lipschitz constant $L$, then
   $$
   |p\circ \phi(x_{k+1})-p\circ \phi(x_{k})|\le L|\phi(x_{k+1})-\phi(x_{k})|.
   $$
   If $\phi$ is BV, so is $p\circ \phi$.
2. Let $p\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be strictly increasing. If $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^n$ is a partition of $I$, then $\{p(x_k)\}_{k=0}^n$ is also  partition of $I$ (after adding the point $x=1$ and removing repeated points if necessary.) Then
   $$
   \sum|\phi\circ p(x_{k+1})-\phi\circ p(x_k)|\le\|\phi\|_{BV}.
   $$
3. If $p$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism so is $p^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, this confirms my hypothesis. Please change notations (in my question I used $\phi$ for the function and $p$ for the diffeo) and I accept the answer.

Comment: Notation changed.